# What is this component marked DB?

Tags: identification

What is this component marked with DB3? It is from an inductor from a tube light.

[image: Component]

I don't think it is a diode, as it has no bands.

What is this?

Note: Picture is from internet. I have an almost identical ballast to this one, and it has the DB3 in that location.

Comment: possibly a diac?

Comment: ^ +1. http://in.element14.com/stmicroelectronics/db3/diac-32v-2a-do-35/dp/9802231

Comment: Yep. Read "ballast", thought "diac".

Comment: My guess is a "DB3 Series 32 V 2 A Trigger Diode with Fixed Voltage Reference DIAC - DO-35.  PDF available via website below. "http://www.futureelectronics.com/en/technologies/electromechanical/circuit-protection/protection-thyristors/Pages/3171444-DB3.aspx?IM=0#sthash.BuSXDtQV.dpuf

Comment: Why all the downvotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is DIAC - there is link http://www.spiratronics.com/data/1540.pdf .